# cmake + xcode : error 'Build setting PRODUCT_NAME undefined'

Tags: c++, c, xcode, build, cmake

I'm using *cmake 2.8.3* to generate a C/C++ project file for *xcode 3.2.5* ; the build goes generally fine, but I have to manually set the "Product Name" each time I generate the xcode project (in *Project / Edit Project Settings / Packaging*).

If I fail to set this product name, *xcode* refuses to build the project, and exits reporting the following error :

- `Build setting PRODUCT_NAME undefined`

Is it possible to set this value with *cmake* ? or go without defining a *Product Name* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have do you tried something like this?

```
 set_target_properties(your_target PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_NAME "aaa")
```

I've replaced Mac OS X with Linux on my MacBook, so I can't check this suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I had the impression that the PRODUCT_NAME was a 'projet' value for XCode, and not a 'target' property. I will give it a try.

Comment: Great ! thanks for the tip ; it seems that I cannot reproduce the problem : I've changed/completed my cmake files to build with 'make' and xcode does no more complain. But your method allows to explicitly control the product name, thanks !

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, the command is

`set_target_property(your_target PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_NAME "aaa")`